# Можно ли получить список рекомендуемых для добавления индексов?

Tags: sql-server

Можно ли как-нибудь в режиме реального времени получить все закешированные планы запросов и увидеть в них рекомендации от MS SQL по добавлению индексов?

Comment: sys.dm_exec_cached_plans для кэшов

Comment: @Konst а рекомендации входят в эти планы?

Comment: по отсутствующим индексам придётся самому https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1634/using-sql-server-dmvs-to-identify-missing-indexes/

Comment: @Konst, тогда, как я понимаю, кеши планов мне не нужно и вся необходимая инфа есть в во вьхах, которые по ссылке?

Comment: для анализа на отсутствующие индексы, да достаточно.